# MVC Javascript in ForEach Statement

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I wonder if someone can please advise, I am using MVC with Rateit.js and trying to populate the chosen ratings value into a textboxfor to allow saving the value.  I have got this far:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
     @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Answer, new { id = "t" + @item.ID })
     <div class="rateit" id="@item.ID" onclick="setValue()">
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function setValue() {                               
             document.getElementById("t"+@item.ID).value = 
             $('#@item.ID').rateit('value');
         }
     </script>
}
```

On the view 3 records are returned, this works as intended on the last record but not the first 2 and I'm now rather stuck! any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Add one parameter to `setValue(id)` and pass it like this `onclick="setValue(@item.ID)"` and use it in `document.getlement` the main problem you are facing because you are adding same function thrice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the setValue function.. it will always be the last one.

Modify this:

`<div class="rateit" id="@item.ID" onclick="setValue()">`

To:

`<div class="rateit" id="@item.ID" onclick="setValue('@item.ID')">`

Take the script out the loop and modify it to this:

```
function setValue(id) {                               
    document.getElementById("t"+id).value = $('#'+id).rateit('value');
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you so much for the quick response!

Comment: @Cuppachee Accept the answer as the correct one using the green tick in this case :)

Comment: That should be done now, had a 5 minute counter for some reason! thanks very much again :)